# Sql Query for JSP Insert. Where i Need for one Column Value from a Select Where statement.

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, select, insert

I am reading a Table :

Certificate, where i have mentioned the Cert_ID Auto Increment and Cert_Name n Desc.

Now i have declared Cert_ID as PK. which relates with FK in Coach table of same Datatype.

Coach Table

CREATE TABLE School.CricketCoach
(Coach_Index INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Coach_ID VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Coach_FName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Coach_LName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Coach_Email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Coach_Password VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Coach_DOB DATE NOT NULL,
Coach_DOJ DATE NOT NULL,
Coach_Phone VARCHAR(25),
Coach_Address VARCHAR(25),
Coach_City VARCHAR(25),
Coach_County VARCHAR(25),
Coach_Country VARCHAR(25),
Coach_NIC VARCHAR(25),
Coach_AcountCreateDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Coach_AcountModifiedDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Cert_ID VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,

### PRIMARY KEY (Coach_Index)) ENGINE=InnoDB

Certificate Table
CREATE TABLE School.CricketCertificate
(Cert_ID INTEGER(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Cert_Name VARCHAR(25),
Cert_Description VARCHAR(25),

### PRIMARY KEY (Cert_ID))

Now i have a Form where i am calling the Certificate Table"Cert_Name" to be used in a "Select-Option". Its displaying perfectly as i have called through TreeSet and It display in the Form.

Now my Question is I am getting Cert_Name from the Form .. But how will i make Query to input it in Cert_ID in FK Field in Coach Table.

Should i make 2-Different Prepared Statement? and should i store it in SET? Map or Just String?

I am passing this on the Form Start from doget method.. through a Java Class:

Class is Account: 
public TreeSet cricketCertificate() throws SQLException{

```
    String sql= "select Cert_Name from CricketCertificate";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){

    certifyLevel.add(rs.getString("Cert_Name"));
            }
    rs.close();
    return certifyLevel;
}
```

Servlet: doGet: 
Account cer = new Account(conn);

```
        TreeSet<String> certificate = new TreeSet<String>();
        try {
            certificate= cer.cricketCertificate();  
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        request.setAttribute("certificatename", certificate);
```

JSP Form:
*Coach Certificate

```
            <select name ="certificate" class="req">
            <option >Select</option>

            <%
            TreeSet<String> cert =    (TreeSet<String>)request.getAttribute("certificatename");
                for (String element : cert ){%>

                <option >
                <%=element%>
                </option>
                    <%} %>

            </select>
```

I need Cert_ID to be send directly through a Query .. is this possible?
I m out of SQL for a Long Time... I m just stucked :S 
INSERT INTO School.CricketCoach (Coach_ID, Coach_FName, Coach_LName, Coach_Email, Coach_Password, Coach_DOB, Coach_DOJ, Coach_Phone, Coach_Address, Coach_City, Coach_County, Coach_Country, Coach_NIC, Cert_ID) VALUES ('CRC00001MA', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'email@gmail.com', 'password', '1982/01/22', '2014/04/01', '0042358458236', 'Crang', 'Buch', 'Buch', 'Ro', '11111111111111','select Cert_ID from CricketCertificate where Cert_Name="ICC LEVEL 1"');

Comment: get rid of the quotes in the select Cert_ID sql... and it might work.

Comment: i had to make a Seperate prepared statement n insert the value.